# This application is modifying the autolayout engine from a background thread - ios9

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, ios9, xcode7

```
let url = NSURL(string: "http://api.mdec.club:3500/news?")

let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL(url!) {
    (data, response, error) in

    self.jsonResult = try! NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers) as! NSMutableArray

    self.tableView.reloadData()
}

task.resume()
```

I don't understand why I'm getting this error. I have to put the `reloadData()` method inside `task` because I have to wait till the get the data. How else can I reload the table view without getting this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How else can I reload the table view without getting this error?

You step out to the main thread in order to call `reloadData`, like this:

```
let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL(url!) {
    (data, response, error) in
    self.jsonResult = try! NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers) as! NSMutableArray
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

Always do that *any* time you touch the interface from code that was called on a background thread. You must never never never never touch the interface except on the main thread.

Comment: Actually, it isn't very wise to modify `self.jsonResult` on a background thread either, so you might want to put _both_ lines inside the `dispatch_async` call.

Comment: it works thanks! Will accept answer in 4 minutes. ;)

Comment: matt can you explain why just so I know why I'm doing what I'm doing if I put the jsonResult in the dispatch

Comment: The correct thing to do would be to do the deserialization in the background, then the assignment to `self.jsonResult` on the main queue just before the reload.

Comment: @nhgrif very good point, I had not teased it far enough apart

Comment: @nhgrif but why? (just want to know)

Comment: @Schuey999 Which part are you asking why about?

Comment: @nhgrif why the jsonResult should not be on the background thread

Comment: Because presumably you're using `jsonResult` as the data for your table.  If you modify it in the background, you can get something like an index out of bounds if say your table was originally loading 10 rows, but you just overwrote `jsonResult` with something that would only have 3 rows.